# DIV's are not alighning properly

Tags: html, css

I am having trouble with placing my div's in the right position. I made some changes, but it does not work. I would like to put all elements in one row, but title is not aligning properly with the logo. I thought that the problem is in grid, but it is not.

Here is my code.

```html
<body <?php body_class('compass_theme'); ?>>
        <div class="container_24">
            <div class="grid_24">
                <div class="page_content_wrapper">
                    <div class="header animated">
                        <div class="grid_10 alpha">
                            <div class="logo grid_10 alpha" id="logomob">
                                <a href="<?php echo home_url(); ?>"><img src="<?php if (compass_get_option('compass_logo') != '') { ?><?php echo compass_get_option('compass_logo'); ?><?php } else { ?><?php echo get_template_directory_uri(); ?>/images/logo.png<?php } ?>" alt="<?php bloginfo('name'); ?> logo"/></a>
                            </div>

       <div class="titleText grid_14 alpha">
       
        <h1 id="title">
        
         <span id="title-top">Adriatic Yacht</span></br>
         <span id="title-bottom">Professionals</span>    
        
        </h1>
        
        <h2 id="slogan">We can repair everything, except human lives!</h2>
       
       </div>
                        </div>
      
      <div class="grid_14 alpha contactIcons" id="desktop">
      
                            <div class="grid_6 alpha" id="phone">
       
        <i class="fa fa-phone-square" aria-hidden="true"></i>
        <p class="contact">+382-67-507-234</p>
       
       </div>
       
       <div class="grid_6 alpha contactIcons" id="email">
       
        <i class="fa fa-envelope-square" aria-hidden="true"></i>
        <p class="contact">info@adriatic-yacht.pro</p>  
        
       
       </div>
       
       <div class="grid_6 alpha contactIcons" id="skype">
       
        <i class="fa fa-skype" aria-hidden="true"></i>
        <p class="contact">ID: adriaticyacht</p>
        
       
       </div>
                        </div>

      <div class="grid_14 alpha1" id="mobile">
       
       
       <section class="deskContact">
        
        <i class="fa fa-skype" aria-hidden="true"></i>
        <p class="contact">ID: adriaticyacht</p>      
       
       </section>    
       
       <section class="deskContact">
             
        <i class="fa fa-envelope-square" aria-hidden="true"></i>
        <p class="contact">info@adriatic-yacht.pro</p>
        
       </section>
       
       <section class="deskContact">
       
        <i class="fa fa-phone-square" aria-hidden="true"></i>
        <p class="contact">+382-67-507-234</p>
        
       </section>
        
       
                        </div>
      
      <div class="clear"></div>    
     </div>
```

Comment: We need your CSS. Please only share applicable code too.

Comment: Is it OK if I post like this https://jsfiddle.net/ZairR/wk2j0fb8/

Comment: @BorM no, not really. At the minimum add your CSS to your post and create a Stack Snippet. If you cannot figure out how to create a Stack Snippet, add the JSFiddle. Also, don't include your PHP, just generated markup.